# c++ How to assert char array or not, check if a char array start with "0" or contain "0"

Tags: c++, arrays

I got a function that turn char array into integer, how to check if a given array is char or not to assert code, how to check if that char array is starts with, contain "0". And this an example of my code :
thank you

```
void arrToString(char sArr[]) {
    // integer array declare
    int iArr[strlen(sArr)];
    assert(!isdigit(sArr)); // what are the conditions that I should put
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sArr); i++) {
        iArr[i] = sArr[i];
        cout << sArr[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    char stringArr[] = "121212";
    arrToString(stringArr);
}
```

Comment: The argument to `isdigit()` must be a `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: `int iArr[strlen(sArr)];` variable length arrays are non-standard, so this probably doesn't do what you are looking for.

Comment: What's the purpose of `iArr`? You fill it in, but never use it.

Comment: If you just want to check if the char array contains `'0'`, use `std::find()`.

Comment: iArr is the new integer array that will contain the new converted one, and I used it inside the loop

Comment: Your question appears to be an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Why are you copying the elements of `char` to `int`? If you want to assert `not char`, just include your `isdigit(sArr[i])` inside the loop. If your values fit in `char`, they will fit in `int` (and be the same values), so for all practical purposes, you could simply extract the digits to a separate `char` array. Copying to `int` will not convert the ASCII digits to their integer values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are actually asking for.
I hope spiting problem into simple questions and answers clarify and help solve your problem.

> How I can check if char array contain non-digit character and assert if contain?

```
void arrToStringAssertWhenContainNonDigit(char sArr[]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(sArr); i++) {
        assert(isdigit(sArr[i]));
        cout << sArr[i];
    }
}
```

> How to use assert?

It might be not intuitive. I guess here might be root of the mater of your problem. The best is example

```
assert(true);    // This always pass. Assert is not thrown and assert window is not shown
assert(false);   // This always fail. Assert is always thrown and assert window is shown
assert(isdigit(sArr[i])); // Assert is thrown when sArr[i] is NOT a digit
```

For convenience "assert" might be remembered as "ensure that"

> How to assert when array start from digit zero?

One line implementation could be:

```
assert(strlen(stringArr) == 0 || stringArr[0] != '0');
```

> How to assert when array contain zero digit?

```
void arrToStringAssertWhenContainZero(char sArr[]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(sArr); i++) {
        assert(sArr[i] != '0');
        cout << sArr[i];
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Do not mislead zero character '0', with zero digit 0 and with zero terminating character which is '\0'. Each of it has a different meaning and improperly used may change code execution in unexpected way.